# symfony не принимает произвольный header

Tags: php, apache, symfony

Задеплоил приложение на сервер. И при каждом запросе при формирований объекта headers в Request, нет заголовка Authorization который отправляется с клиента. С помощью nelmio-cors уже в allow-headers указал этот заголовок, даже в обработчике события на Response добавил, что бы этот заголовок принимался.
Вот ответ от сервера с заголовками. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что в объекте headers в этот момент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Снизу null* это я попытался достать этот заголовок Authorization, но его нет. Хотя он отправлен.

А да на локальном компе с помощью стандартного php-dev сервера все нормально работает.

Comment: Вам не приходит в голову, что заголовки принимает не symfony, а HTTP сервер?

Comment: Конечно же приходит. Поэтому я и указал apache в метках.

Comment: Ну так и разбирайтесь с Апачем.